# Meaning of 準備ができたものから

Tags: reading-comprehension

[Context](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011990471000/k10011990471000.html):

> １０円や５０円などほかの硬貨も、**準備ができたものから**作り始めます。
>   They will also start making other coins such as the 10 and 50 yen *from the thing they were able to prepare*.

I can't even guess at what 準備ができたものから is meant to mean in this sentence. What is もの referring to? The context doesn't help me at all.

Edit: Presumably it is simply "after they've made preparations", but I still don't understand the ものから part well.

Comment: This もの refers to 硬貨.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This から stands for the starting point of sequence, just like English *from* in "from the largest to smallest". [The dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/45491/meaning/m0u/) says:

> **５** 動作・作用の開始順序や発端を示す。「先着の人から入場してください」

So,

> 準備ができたものから
>   *in the order they reach readiness*
>   *(starting) from what has been made ready*